# How should I mock this method call?

Tags: mockito

Here is the method I am trying to unit test:

```
public void setToCache(final String cacheKey, final String value) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(cacheKey)) {
        throw new NamedSystemException(
                ENamedSystemExceptionCode.ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION,
                "Cache Key is null or empty.");

    } else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
        throw new NamedSystemException(
                ENamedSystemExceptionCode.ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION,
                "Value is null or empty.");
    }

    final Jedis jedis = getJedisClient();

    try {
        jedis.set(cacheKey, value);
        jedis.expire(cacheKey, 60);

    } finally {
        jedis.close();
    }
}
```

How can I mock the `Jedis` object?

Comment: Basically, you can't. You could imagine spying on the object and mock getJedisClient(), but since it's a static method, Mockito can't do anything. To make your code testable, avoid static methods, and use dependency injection to inject your dependencies, rather than looking them up.

Comment: @JBNizet I have changed it to an instance method. Should jedis be retrieved from instance as well for it to be mockable?

Comment: Yes. Mockito can't mock static methods.

Comment: Or you can use PowerMock as described here [Mocking static methods with Mockito][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe your `getJedisClient()` method?

If this method is using an object that is injected in your class (either a direct instance of `Jedis` or a service proding `Jedis`), you can easily mock it using

```
Mockito.mock(yourObject);
```

It really depends on your `getJedisClient()` implementation.